# How can I use html5 videos in splidejs slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, splidejs

How can I use the "splidejs" slider with the “splide-extension-video” with the following requirements?

1. The slider moves automatically after a certain time (works)
2. The current visible video always starts from the beginning (does not work). Currently it stops when changing and then resumes at the last position.

The problem is that the preview image appears first before the video. But if the video doesn't start from the beginning, it doesn't fit together anymore. You can either deactivate the still image somehow (?) or always play the video from the beginning (?).

```
const splide = new Splide( '.splide', {
  width: '100%',
  arrows: false,
  type : 'loop',
  autoplay: true,
  interval: 4000,
  perPage : 1,
  speed : 2000,
  video: {
    autoplay: true,
    loop : true,
    mute : true,
    hideControls: true,
    disableOverlayUI: true,
    playerOptions: { htmlVideo: {} },
  }
} );

splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to html5 video, `mediaElement.currentTime = 0;` is what you need, probably on the event of `move` of the slider. Yes, it's a little crude, but it works.

```js
const splide = new Splide('.splide', {
  width: '100%',
  arrows: true,
  type: 'loop',
  autoplay: true,
  interval: 4000,
  perPage: 1,
  speed: 2000,
  video: {
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    mute: true,
    hideControls: false,
    disableOverlayUI: true,
    playerOptions: {
      htmlVideo: {}
    },
  }
});

splide.on('move', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.splide video').forEach(function(video) {
    video.currentTime = 0
  })
});

splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.8.0/dist/js/splide-extension-video.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.8.0/dist/css/splide-extension-video.min.css">


<section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-html-video="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/50">
      </li>
      <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-html-video="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/50">
      </li>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: IT goldman: Thanks, you made my day, currentTime was the key! I would have further question, see below...

Answer (score 0):

How do you manage to activate autoplay again after manually switching to another slide by pressing the pagination button and after leaving the slider area? Currently autoplay:play event is not further called, the last one is autoplay:pause. I just want it to automatically switch to the next video after the interval time after a manual switch.

Thanks...

Comment: it seems that if you un-focus the pagination, it will automatically continue

Comment: Unfortunately not if you pressed manually on the pagination buttons. The "autoplay:play" event is not further called. Do you maybe know how to reactivate the autoplay:play event?

Comment: The next thing that bothers are the static images. Isn't there a way to only show videos that start playing when you switch?

Comment: I'm now also testing with short videos and I'm seeing unpleasant transitions. No matter what events active, inactive, move, moved,... unfortunately nothing works. I think this slider is not suitable for videos...

Comment: i don't know. maybe this plugin has it's [issues](https://github.com/Splidejs/splide/issues), maybe not. personally i would try a slider plugin and a video player plugin, and combine them using events. but it's possible this or another plugin works as well